# How to read the particular value from Ping result

Tags: regex, powershell, networking, ping

I am trying to read values from below ping results, like I want to read Received value as 4 or Lost value as 0 using regular expression.

```
Ping statistics for 74.125.200.94:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 63ms, Maximum = 64ms, Average = 63ms
```

I am trying with below but no go, Any help?

```
$test = ping google.co.in
$test -match "^Average = \((\d+)\)$"
```

Comment: You know that `$test` will be an array?

Comment: @vonPryz - Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `[regex]::Match` to grab the information:

```
$test = ping google.co.in

$match = [regex]::Match($test, 'Received = (\d+), Lost = (\d+)')
$received = $match.Groups[1].Value
$lost = $match.Groups[2].Value
```

Comment: This works, but if I change the values in Match(), then for some reason, I dont get any output here.

$test = ping google.co.in

$match = [regex]::Match($test, 'Received = (\d+), Sent = (\d+)')
$received = $match.Groups[1].Value
$sent = $match.Groups[2].Value

Comment: I would recommend you to use multiple [regex]::Match calls, one for received: `[regex]::Match($test, 'Received = (\d+)')` then one for Sent:  `[regex]::Match($test, 'Sent = (\d+)'`

Comment: thank you, that solves the issue. Any way to get the values in one line? as it becomes the script lengthy.

Comment: You could use a single match with the or operator and the following regex: `Received = (\d+)|Lost = (\d+)|Sent = (\d+)` but then I would use named capture groups instead of accessing the groups by index. Please consider accept the answer.

Comment: Brandi - What should I use instead of $received = $match.Groups[1].Value? if I want to use named capture groups. Sorry I am not that expert.

Comment: If your regex looks like this: `Received = (?<received>\d+)|Lost = (?<lost>\d+)|Sent = (?<sent>\d+)` you can write `$match.Groups['received'].Value` and `$match.Groups['sent'].Value` ....

Comment: Please start accepting answers if your question is solved. Read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Sorry Martin, I am getting an error after I have implemented login in script, please find the script below
$test = ping google.co.in

$match = [regex]::Match($test, 'Received = (?<received>\d+)|Lost = (?<lost>\d+)|Sent = (?<sent>\d+)')

$received = $match.Groups['received'].Value
$lost = $match.Groups['lost'].Value
$sent = $match.Groups['sent'].Value

Write-Host $received
Write-Host $lost
Write-Host $sent