# Parse ping command output

Tags: python, regex, windows, powershell

I would like to parse the output of the `ping` command under Windows by using Python. In particular the min, max and average RTT.

I have the following piece of code:

```
from sys import platform
import re

if platform == "linux" or platform == "darwin":
    command=["ping", "-c", "3", "-i", "0.2", IP]
    timeout=0.5
else:
    command=["ping", "-n", "1", IP]
    timeout=0.2  proc=subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    [out, err]=proc.communicate(timeout=timeout)
    if proc.returncode == 0:
        if platform == "linux" or platform == "darwin":
            # rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 578.263/917.875/1013.707/132.095 ms
            avgRTT=re.search("rtt min/avg/max/mdev = (\d+.\d+)/(\d+.\d+)/(\d+.\d+)/(\d+.\d+)", str(out)).group(2)
        else:
            # Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: Minimum = 63ms, Maximum = 64ms, Average = 63ms
            avgRTT=re.search("Minimum = (\d+), Maximum = (\d+), Average = (\d+)", str(out))
            print(avgRTT.group())
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
```

It works well under GNU/linux and mac os X while does not work for Windows. I also tried with the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506287/how-to-read-the-particular-value-from-ping-result) without success.

Comment: forgetting the `ms` part after the digit. `"Minimum = (\d+)ms, Maximum = (\d+)ms, Average = (\d+)ms"`

Comment: also use `out.decode()` not `str(out)`

Answer (score 1):

I've taken your code and just changed a few small things.  `ms` was missing in the regex for `windows` and just had to add some includes and spacing (probably in part due to StackOverflow formatting).  This now runs on my `windows 7.0` box just fine.  You should just be able to copy/paste/hit go and get the desired results :)

```
from sys import platform
import subprocess
import re

IP = "127.0.0.1"

if platform == "linux" or platform == "darwin":
    command=["ping", "-c", "3", "-i", "0.2", IP]
    timeout=0.5
else:
    command=["ping", "-n", "1", IP]
    timeout=0.2
    proc=subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

try:
    [out, err]=proc.communicate(timeout=timeout)
    if proc.returncode == 0:
        if platform == "linux" or platform == "darwin":
            # rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 578.263/917.875/1013.707/132.095 ms
            avgRTT=re.search("rtt min/avg/max/mdev = (\d+.\d+)/(\d+.\d+)/(\d+.\d+)/(\d+.\d+)", str(out)).group(2)
        else:
            # Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: Minimum = 63ms, Maximum = 64ms, Average = 63ms
            avgRTT=re.search("Minimum = (\d+)ms, Maximum = (\d+)ms, Average = (\d+)", str(out))
            print(avgRTT.group())
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank, you forgot last ms too :). However, I'm using a different language from English and I solved by adding two more space: Minimum = (\d+)ms,  Maximum =  (\d+)ms,  Average =  (\d+)ms